# Установка PHP Storm в xubuntu

Tags: phpstorm, xubuntu

Доброго времени, уважаемые коллеги. Прошу помочь разобраться с установкой IDE в Xubuntu. Я пользовался CodeLobster из под винды, однако под линукс его нет. Если можно, опишите наиболее подробно этапы установки. Что есть: есть скачанный и распакованный архив с программой в директории `/home/developer/Загрузки/PhpStorm-172.3544.41/`
Как мне с помощью терминала установить IDE?
Спасибо.

Comment: 1) sh /home/User/PhpStorm-172.3544.41/bin/phpstorm.sh (меняете на свой ) 2) Фиксируете ссылку на левом меню правым кликом по иконке запущенной программы -> Lock in launcher.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

написать в терминале:

```
cd /home/developer/Загрузки/PhpStorm-172.3544.41/
cd bin
```

получится

```
/home/developer/Загрузки/PhpStorm-172.3544.41/bin
```

далее написать команду:

```
./phpstorm.sh
```

этот скрипт запустит IDE

но если не запустится нужно установить  Java 8 для Ubuntu делается так:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install java-common oracle-java8-installer
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-set-default
source /etc/profile
```

Comment: Насколько я помню, это было нужно сделать только в первый раз, а потом приложение было доступно через... забыл как называется... быстрый запуск по Super+Space.

Comment: @Nick Volynkin после первого запуска ярлык появится в `меню прилодений`